# Type Mismatch in Vba Function

Tags: vba, excel

Following code is giving me Type Mismatch error. Can someone please correct this code. I have to find a string value in the First column of my excel sheet.

```
Private Function find_RuleId_Column(page As String, strFind As String) As Range
Dim Gcell As Range
Set Gcell = Sheets(page).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1000)).find(What:=strFind, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat _
   :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False)
Set find_RuleId_Column = Gcell
End Function
```

Comment: Please highlight your code and avoid splitting the question over the comment section.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum . I think code is clearly visible now.

Comment: Code looks like it works fine, but according to your description you probably want to remove the `After:=ActiveCell` condition.

Comment: I would guess that if `find` doesn't find a match, it will return an error and you are then trying to assign an error to a `Range` object. Consider returning something that general enough to be a `Range` and an error like a `variant`.

Comment: Thanks Callum. The problem is resolved after removing After := ActiveCell.

Comment: No problem, see my answer for how to simplify (you don't need the Gcell range) and also best to error handle with `Is Nothing` when using the results of this function

Answer (score 2):

This function isn't really doing much more than the `Find` function does in the first place, so maybe it's worth considering if you actually need the function.

That aside, your function can be simplified - see below. Your issue was probably because of the `Activecell` part - as I mentioned in the comments.

> ```
> Private Function FindHeader(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal HeaderName As String) As Range
>     Set FindHeader = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range("A1").Resize(1,1000).Find(HeaderName, lookat:=xlWhole)
> End Function
> ```

Note that your function will return `Nothing` if a header with that name cannot be found. So when you call the function check `Is Nothing`. For example:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim header As Range
    Set header = FindHeader("Sheet1", "TestHeader")

    If Not header Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Header is in " & header.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works as expected, I replaced the ActiveCell part as well as changed the range so that it looks at column 1 instead of A1:A1000:

```
Private Function find_RuleId_Column(page As String, strFind As String) As Range
    Dim Gcell As Range
    Set Gcell = Sheets(page).Columns(1).Find(What:=strFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat _
       :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False)
        Set find_RuleId_Column = Gcell
End Function

Sub foo()
    If Not find_RuleId_Column("Sheet1", "SearchItem") Is Nothing Then MsgBox find_RuleId_Column("Sheet1", "SearchItem").Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula

```
=MATCH(B1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,"!A1:A1000")),0)
```

where `B1` contains the string you want to search and `A1` contains the name of sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when the ActiveCell isn't within the range A1:ALL1. However, there is another error looming which will occur when `strFind` isn't found. Range Gcell will be Nothing if the search was unsuccessful. You should test for that. However, you don't want the range, it seems. The code below will return the column number, as the function's name suggests. If `strFind` isn't found an error will occur which the code ignores. The function will return 0 (zero) if no match was found.

```
Private Function find_RuleId_Column(page As String, strFind As String) As Long

    Dim Gcell As Range

    With Sheets(page)
        Set Gcell = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1000))
        On Error Resume Next
        find_RuleId_Column = Gcell.Find(What:=strFind, _
                                        After:=.Cells(1, 1000), _
                                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False).Column
    End With
End Function
```